# Random Path in Circle, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

```
I'm trying to generate a random path from the center of a circle and count how     many steps it takes to exit the circle, my programming language is python 2.7. I've imported random and numpy.
```

I've written some pseudo code to help me keep in mind what I want to accomplish:

```
Start at center of circle
Keep track of step count
Step distance=1 step
Radius of Circle=500 steps
While location<500 steps from center:
    take=1 step in random angle direction
    continue while loop
How many steps?
```

I'm having trouble with every part of this code. I don't know where to begin,
I imagine I'd have to append to an array so I can know when I've exited the circle but I have no idea how to keep track of my coordinates.

***Update***

This is the code I have written so far, it will be updated as I make changes:

```
#Start code
#Import modules
import numpy

#Define constants
r=500
step=1
step_count=0

#Defining origin in circle
x=0
y=0


#While inside the circle
while (x**2+y**2)**(1./2.)<=r:
    x_step=step*numpy.cos(numpy.random.beta(0.,2.,1./180.)
    y_step=step*numpy.sin(numpy.random.beta(0.,2.,1./180.)
    x+=x_step
    y+=y_step
    step_count+=1

#Print answer
print step_count
```

Things to correct:

- y_step=step*numpy.sin(numpy.random.beta(0.,2.,1./180.)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

- ???

Comment: You should start by creating a circle in your code and setting your coordinations to the centre of it

Comment: You should really post some code as part of your question to get any help from programmers on StackOverflow.

Comment: You do not really need to program in a circle at all. All you need is an x and y coordinate which you will continually add to. For each step calculate the distance between the starting x,y-position and your current position and once that distance is more than the radius of your circle, you have exited the circle

Comment: I appreciate these answers. They give me a good idea of ways to calculate the distance to the origin of the circle, but I still have no idea how to write a code to do this. So far my experience with codes have been **random numbers** in **if** statements

Comment: There must be **some** code you **can** write. Update your question with that code. We know it will be wrong, but that's why you are here to get help with code that is wrong.

Comment: @quamrana edit the initial post? I'm having trouble writing my code in the comments.
I'm new to stackexchange

Comment: Ok, I forget there are some restrictions for new users. Are you able to edit your question? There should be the word *edit* just below the tags just below the body of the question.

Comment: @quamrana yes, i'll do that.

Comment: @quamrana thank you for tolerating us noobies.

Comment: Ok, first question to you is: Mathematically how do you determine if a point (x,y) is within a circle of radius r?

Comment: if (x,y)<radius of circle that (x,y) is inside the circle. @quamrana

Comment: Yeah, that's not it mathematically, I was thinking of using `sin()` or x^2 kind of stuff.

Comment: x=r*cos(angle), y=r*sin(angle), (x,y)<500

Comment: So, perhaps you could update your question (or perhaps start an answer of your own) with a function that does this using `math`, or perhaps `numpy` can do this? I'm not familiar with `numpy`.

Comment: @quamrana math.cos or math.sin perform the same way. Isn't that what I wrote in my updated code above?

Comment: No, you need the inverse. From (x,y) you need to derive r and then test for r<500.

Comment: You already have the origin. Just make a distance function (simple euclidian) and break the loop when its superior to the radius. You just need the trigonometry to calculate the next step (the input is in radians btw), not to check if a position is inside a circle (with know origin).

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the code once again. This seems to be better, but I am having problem with syntax.

Comment: @armatita what do you mean with "break" the loop? I have not used that function yet.

Comment: You are missing some closing parenthesis

Comment: I mean as in the [break](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) python statement. You do something like "if distance to the origin superior to radius -> break". If you use it inside the while loop it will stop it. You can also build a system of flags and do `while flag`. Changing the flag to false will stop the loop.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using numpy as opposed to something more beginner friendly like the built in math and random packages?  You are not using numpy correctly.

Comment: @rtaft it is just what i was taught with from the beginning, go figure. thank you for you time.

Comment: @armatita the while loop breaks when the value is outside of the radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not want to leave this thread unanswered. This is an example of my final code:

```
#Define constants
r=500
step=1
step_count=0

#Defining origin in circle
x=0
y=0

#While inside the circle
while (x**2+y**2)**(1./2.)<=r:
    theta=2*math.pi*random.random()
    x_step=step*math.cos(theta)
    y_step=step*math.sin(theta)
    x+=x_step
    y+=y_step
    step_count+=1

#Print answer
print "It took",step_count,"steps to exit the circle at (",x,",",y,") in (x,y) format)
```

Many thank to all who answered, particularly to @quamrana

Answer (score 0):

So, you're almost there.

This is a solution that just uses `math`.  (Also python3)

```
import math, random

#Define constants
r = 500
step = 1

#define state
step_count = 0

#Defining origin in circle
x=0
y=0

#While inside the circle
while (x**2 + y**2)**(1./2.) <= r:
    angle = 2 * math.pi * random.random() 
    x_step = step * math.cos(angle)
    y_step = step * math.sin(angle)
    x += x_step
    y += y_step
    step_count += 1

#Print answer
print(step_count,x,y)
```

Sample output:

```
433126 65.02643317539659 495.86845856661375
```

Note how I've calculated a random angle once and used that to calculate a step.